# Google Fit: Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S5 not counting background steps

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

In my app I create a subscription to record steps, which works fine. The problem is when the screen is closed Google Fit doesn't count any steps. This only happens on the S4 and S5. It's worked on two S3's, a Nexus 7, and an S7. I've even compared my step count to the actual Google Fit app and the background steps aren't counted there either.

Kinda stumped on this one. Not sure why it would behave differently on certain devices.

In onStart() I call buildFitnessClient().

```
public void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.  What to do?
                            // Subscribe to some data sources!
                            subscribe();
                            readData();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                            result.toString());
                }
            })
            .build();

    subscribe();

    //readData();
}

/**
 * Record step data by requesting a subscription to background step data.
 */
public void subscribe() {
    // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
    // active, fitness data will start recording.
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode()
                                == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

public int startPedometer() {
    listener = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                if (dataPoint.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                    Log.d("JUNE 12: ", "" + val);

                    presenter.setActiveFlag();

                    if (!presenter.checkPauseBool()) {
                        val.setInt(0);
                        presenter.putPauseBool();
                    }

                    mInitialNumberOfSteps += val.asInt();

                    //readData();

                    //_googleFit = new GoogleFit(getContext());


                    //int googleFitSteps = _googleFit.getSteps(_startTime);


                    if (getActivity() == null) {
                        return;
                    } else if (isAdded()) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            //_dailyStepTotal.setText("Steps: " + mInitialNumberOfSteps);

                                                            double cals = (_totalCalories - (mInitialNumberOfSteps * 0.044));
                                                            _remCals = (int) Math.round(cals);

                                                            if (isAdded()) {
                                                                _caloriesRemaining.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.crumble_calories_remaining, String.valueOf(_remCals)));
                                                            }

                                                            double eightyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.8;
                                                            eighty = (int) Math.round(eightyPercent);

                                                            double sixtyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.6;
                                                            sixty = (int) Math.round(sixtyPercent);

                                                            double fortyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.4;
                                                            forty = (int) Math.round(fortyPercent);

                                                            double twentyPercent = _totalCalories * 0.2;
                                                            twenty = (int) Math.round(twentyPercent);

                                                            if ((_remCals <= eighty && _remCals > sixty) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(two);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= sixty && _remCals > forty) && _alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(three);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = false;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= forty && _remCals > twenty) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(four);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals <= twenty && _remCals > 0) && _alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.onBeginCrumbleClick();
                                                                presenter.switchCrumbleImage(five);
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = false;
                                                            } else if ((_remCals == 0 || _remCals < 0) && !_alreadyPlayed) {
                                                                presenter.clearActiveFoodFlag();
                                                                presenter.addToHistory(_totalCalories);
                                                                presenter.saveSteps("0");
                                                                presenter.updateQueue();
                                                                fireworksAnimation();
                                                                _alreadyPlayed = true;
                                                                getActivity().finish();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                        );
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
    SensorRequest req = new SensorRequest.Builder().setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA).setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    result = Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, req, listener);

    //Log.d("Steps: ", "" + result);

    return mInitialNumberOfSteps;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the service isn't killed? If it is killed that would explain why it doesn't count

Comment: There's no service. Google Fit continuously counts steps once the subscription is started unless I'm misinterpreting, "Google Fit stores fitness data from active subscriptions even when your app is not running and restores these subscriptions when the system restarts.".